# How to manage db connections using webpy with SQLObject?

Tags: python, database, web-frameworks, web.py, sqlobject

[Web.py](http://webpy.org) has its own database API, web.db.  It's possible to use SQLObject instead, but I haven't been able to find documentation describing how to do this properly. I'm especially interested in managing database connections.  It would be best to establish a connection at the wsgi entry point, and reuse it.  Webpy cookbook contains an [example](http://webpy.org/cookbook/sqlalchemy) how to do this with SQLAlchemy.  I'd be interested to see how to properly do a similar thing using SQLObject.

This is how I currently do it:

```
class MyPage(object):
  def GET(self):
    ConnectToDatabase()
    ....
    return render.MyPage(...)
```

This is obviously inefficient, because it establishes a new database connection on each query. I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the SQLAlchemy example given, a processor is used, that is, a session is created for each connection and committed when the handler is complete (or rolled back if an error has occurred).

I don't see any simple way to do what you propose, i.e. open a connection at the WSGI entry point.  You will probably need a connection pool to serve multiple clients at the same time. (I have no idea what are the requirements for efficiency, code simplicity and so on, though. Please comment.)

Inserting `ConnectToDatabase` calls into each handler is of course ugly. I suggest that you adapt the cookbook example replacing the SQLAlchemy session with a SQLObject connection.